# Are there other verbs like “be” and “go”?

Tags: etymology, verbs, irregular, suppletion

The verbs *be* and *go* have the nice peculiarity that their various forms (*be*/*was* and *go*/*went*) come from originally distinct verbs. Are there other such verbs?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess not. As stated [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_%28verb%29#Development_of_a_new_preterite):

> **Go** is an irregular verb. Along with **be**, **go** is one of only two verbs with a [suppletive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suppletion) past tense in the English language."

(The link for "suppletive" will point you to the "suppletion" wiki page, where there are examples, also for other languages. *Suppletion* also applies to adjectives, nouns, etc.)

[This](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category%3aEnglish_suppletive_verbs) is another page for the English suppletive verbs, which are only two.

Answer (score 2):

The past participle forms *has awoke* and *has awoken* seem to have almost completely vanished from the English language, but there are lots of people who use the past tense *awoke* ([See Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=has+awakened%2Chas+awoke%2Chas+awoken%2Cshe+awoke%2Cshe+awakened&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=26&smoothing=3)), which means that some people must conjugate *awake* as

> awake, awoke, has awakened.

These forms are from what were originally two different, although very closely related verbs, *awake* and *awaken*.

Comment: Hm, are you [sure](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=has+awoken%2C+have+awoken%2C+had+awoken%2C+is+awoken%2C+are+awoken%2C+was+awoken%2C+were+awoken&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=26&smoothing=3) it has nearly vanished? There do seem to be [quite a few recent instances of *had awoken*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22had%20awoken%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1987,cd_max:2020&lr=lang_en), as just one example.

Comment: Beware! The dragon has awoken!

Comment: Are you sure that some people regard *awake, awoke* and *has awakened* as parts of the same verb? That either they use *awake* (like *has awakened*) for the transitive, or they use *has awakened* (like *awake*) for the intransitive? // If the point is the vowel change form *awake* to *awoke*, then that is ablaut, as in drive/drove/driven.

Comment: If five times as many people use *has awakened* than *has awoken*, and five times as many people use *she awoke* rather than *she awakened*, one would expect that a reasonable large fraction of people conjugate the verb either *awake/awoke/awakened* or *awaken/awoke/awakened*.