# Is 'worse' the only comparative that has neither -er nor more?

Tags: etymology, comparatives, word-formation

There was a question recently [about comparatives](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94992/comparative-adverbs) and it got me thinking about how comparatives are formed.

There are those that take -er and those that use *more* to indicate comparison, but is *worse* the only comparative in English that is intrinsically comparative? That is, it is not necessary to modify it by adding a suffix or a helper.

Why is this the case? Looking at [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=worse&allowed_in_frame=0) seems to indicate that it came into English as a comparative already, which would I think explain its irregular form, but I don't know enough about etymology to know if that is a good guess. Are there other words like this, or is *worse* unique?

Comment: I've been holding out accepting an answer because both just offer a single counterexample and neither one has anything to say with regard to the last paragraph asking about the why. However, it seems we have a [question about suppletion](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37883/good-and-bad-suppletive-adjectives) that has as good an answer as any with regard to the why of these irregularities, so I thought I would include it here.

Comment: Aren't "superior to" and "inferior to" comparatives? Nether uses _-er_ or _more_.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Much/many, more, most* and *little/few, less/fewer, least/fewest* are the positive, comparative, and superlative quantifiers in English. They come in two scales, with affirmative and negative increments.

Note that the negative scale distinguishes count (*few, fewer, fewest*) from mass (*little, less, least*) consistently, while the affirmative scale does so only in the positive degree (*much, many*); *more* and *most* don't distinguish mass from count - *fewer people, less cheese; more people, more cheese*.

Comment: So more = more and fewer = with an -er, but less is different too. So is it just *worse* and *less* then?

Comment: +1 for the insightful note on fewer/less

Answer (score 1):

It's not unique. "Less" is a valid comparative of "little."

Comment: I thought the comparative of *little* was *littler*.

Comment: @KitFox The comparative of *I have little interest in X* is *I have less interest in A than I have in B.* The superlative is *I have the least interest of all of us.*

Comment: I think most people would say `smaller` instead of `littler`.

Comment: @KitFox "Littler" is the comparative when you're talking about size. "Less" is the comparative when you're talking about degree.